# Cannot iterate through Shapes collection

Tags: ms-word, interop, vsto

C# and word interop,
I have a word document with some textboxs (msoTextBox shapes), the problem that I can't iterate through the shapes collection with the code below :

```
foreach (Shape shape in WordDocument.Shapes)
        {}
```

although when setting a breakpoint in the loop line I can see that WordDocument.Shapes.Count returns 4.

I note that textboxs are inserted using open xml sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found there's a problem when textboxes are used.  Take a look at this [solution](http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2010/07/03/find-and-replace-in-word-using-c-net/).

Comment: What exactly is the solution here? Using Range.ShapeRange instead of Document.Shapes?

Comment: @Chris - it appears one has to navigate all the data structures (ugh!) and make changes that way. Not very elegant.  (Code is at the link above.)

Comment: Link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

From [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Word_Automation.aspx?display=Print) :

```
    // Get the word count from all shapes
    foreach (Word.Shape shape in wordDocument.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.TextFrame.HasText < 0)
        {
            count+=GetCountFromRange(shape.TextFrame.TextRange,wordDocument,word);
        }
    }
```

From what you said, you look like you do the right thing.

Can you give us the Error StackTrace ?

PS : I know my question should have been in the comments, but it wouldn't have been readable :)

Answer (score 0):

So,

Replace :

```
foreach (Shape shape in WordDocument.Shapes)
   {
   }
```

By:

```
     foreach (Range rangeStory in WordDocument.StoryRanges)
     {
        foreach (Shape shape in rangeStory.ShapeRange)
        {

        }
     }
```

It's work perfectly.